# How to copy aws s3 files to lightsail bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do we cp s3 files to lightsail bucket files?
I want to copy or move all s3 files to lightsail bucket.

Because lightsail bucket is much cheaper than s3.

Comment: What is a "lightsail bucket"? Buckets only exist in Amazon S3, which is accessible from both Amazon EC2 and Amazon Lightsail instances (and, in fact, from anywhere on the Internet).

Comment: Before this year, Aws only support Amazon S3 for static, media .. etc files. But in this year, they are supporting bucket as same as AWS s3 but cheaper than that. If you access lightsail, you can creat bucket in storage menu of lightsail instance home page.

That's new feature. So it doesn't have many infos about that.
Specially migrate ec2 / s3 to lightsail / lightsail bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I leave solution:

`aws configure`

You need to configure for s3 download.
Just put your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET for s3

`aws s3 cp --recursive s3://<bucketname>/ ./s3`

Download all s3 fles to s3 folder.

`aws configure`

You need to apply lightsail bucket access key id and secret like s3.

`aws s3 cp --recursive ./s3 s3://<bucketname>/`

Then all files are copied.
It's so easy as long as you divide steps.
But I was trying to copy from s3 to lightsail bucket directly.
It's very complicated Because IAM role can't be shared.
I think lightsail is isolated service by s3 and ec2.
So it's cheap and easy.